# Compressing string

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I tried send some data(variable 1 - 4 MB) by http headers,but returned the following error in ajax.response:

HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long.

there something that I can do or the method single is compressing the data? if yes,how I do this?
any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you putting in the header that's so large? I'd expect the majority of your data sent via ajax to be in the form post, not the header.

Comment: I'm sending the file by AJAX. 
How I can read the values receveid by ajax /post in my ASP.NET application?

Comment: There are a couple ways of doing AJAX over ASP.NET - but I'm not aware of any way to upload a file over AJAX. How are you doing what you're currently doing (both client and server)? Maybe we can change it up to use a form post instead of the header.

Comment: add code.. I hope that you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: I actually don't see how this is posting anything at all. As far as I can tell, XMLHttpRequest doesn't contain a member called "file", so I don't think that's doing anything. Uploading via AJAX is supposed to be disabled as a security feature, so I don't think you're going to make this happen directly. If you google it, you'll find a dozen ways of uploading with an AJAX-like user experience, but they generally do it using an iframe or plugin (Flash, java, etc.).

Comment: @Joe: You cannot know, but there methods to do file uplaod using AJAX:
check out my code: http://pastebin.com/DtKGyjZF

It works perfect. (I look the http request using httpFox).
I don't want use Flash/JAVA plugin.
because is required an interpreter installed in computer.

Comment: I was incorrect - the new File API available in modern browsers (i.e. not IE) do allow you to upload files over AJAX. The `ajax.file = file` line in your code is apparently unnecessary though - the work is done in the `ajax.send(file)` call. I set my httpRuntime maxRequestLength value to a high value in web.config as you mentioned below, and I was then able to upload a 100MB file using your technique. The content is apparently not being sent in the headers, so I don't see the HTTP Header problem being related to your file.

Comment: Actually, I used XHR.file in other part of my code.

Joe, I set maxRequestLength to 10240(I can change to 1000000) don't works for me. You can show your web.config file? Thanks!

Comment: Here are the three files I used. I took your example and stripped it down to the bare minimum (and used a little jQuery to make it easier for me to hook up to the events):

Default.aspx: [http://pastebin.com/6ZYzdLjB](http://pastebin.com/6ZYzdLjB)

Default.aspx.cs: [http://pastebin.com/xS8Lc7ni](http://pastebin.com/xS8Lc7ni)

Web.config: [http://pastebin.com/Zm9MSJA6](http://pastebin.com/Zm9MSJA6)

Answer (score 4):

If you're sending around that much data, put it in the body of the request (e.g, in a HTTP POST), not in the headers. Increasing the header size limit (as cwallenpoole suggests) will still cause problems with users who are behind web proxies.

Comment: Yep. I'd go for a POST in the 1st place. That's what it's for. Headers aren't for fat data, and reconfiguring the webserver to make it possible doesn't mean it's right. +1

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would just up the size of the acceptable header. MS [suggests the same](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955585) and gives [instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820129) on how to raise it to 16 MB if necessary (see MaxRequestBytes).

Comment: I'm using the following in my web.config:<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096" />

Comment: That amount is in bytes, I assume, i.e. 4Kb.

Comment: @djacobson: The httpRuntime maxRequestLength property is in kilobytes.

Answer (score 1):

Most http server accept about 8-16KB for the header. Therefore, if your data is too large, just use `POST` method to send it.